# Spring oauth endpoint keeps returning 401

Tags: java, spring, oauth

I have an oauth2 authorization server in spring which is also using spring security. The oauth endpoint (http://localhost:8080/oauth/token) keeps returning 401 even when I try to completely disable authorization.

I tried all of these solutions but none of them worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42019669/2468620

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25674724/2468620

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43931256/2468620

Here is my security config:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    http.httpBasic().disable();
}
```

Here are the logs from processing the request:

```
2017-07-31 16:25:25.875 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/css/**']
2017-07-31 16:25:25.875 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/css/**'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/js/**']
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/js/**'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/images/**']
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/images/**'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/webjars/**']
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/webjars/**'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/error']
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/error'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token']
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : matched
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'GET /logout
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/logout'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2017-07-31 16:25:25.876 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2017-07-31 16:25:25.877 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2017-07-31 16:25:25.877 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2017-07-31 16:25:25.877 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.877 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.877 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.877 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.877 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.877 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.877 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.877 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.877 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
2017-07-31 16:25:25.877 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token; Attributes: [fullyAuthenticated]
2017-07-31 16:25:25.877 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2017-07-31 16:25:25.877 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@3c264a1d, returned: -1
2017-07-31 16:25:25.879 DEBUG 6892 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    ...
```

Comment: are you using spring-secuirity-oauth?

Comment: yes and also spring-boot .. forgot to mention it in the question

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem?